# IIS redirect from subdomain to path

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, url-rewrite-module

Suppose i have real subdomain like this.

test.example.com, is it possible to write a rule for iis to redirect subdomain to test.example.com/SomeStaticPage.html

the rule should work for multi level subdomains, ie.
test.aaa.bbb.example.com should be redirected to 
test.aaa.bbb.example.com/SomeStaticPage.html

Answer (score 1):

Using [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) is very easy, in fact I'm wondering if I don't get the requirements exactly. (do you need different static pages per domain?, or is it really just to redirect to the same "SomestaticPage.html" while keeping the host name when no default page is specified?)

A simple rule like this would do what your question asks:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="RedirectToSomeStatic" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="/SomeStaticPage.html" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    <system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Now, if you were looking for a more complete solution that allows you to specify a page based on the host name, then you could use a rewrite map where you add the host names that should be redirected and which page they should go to. For example the rule below will check if they are requesting "/" and the host name is in the rewrite map and will use that page to redirect, if it is not in the list then it will not do anything:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="RedirectToSomeStatic" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="{C:0}" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HostMap:{HTTP_HOST}}" pattern=".+" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
        </rules>
        <rewriteMaps>
            <rewriteMap name="HostMap">
                <add key="test.example.com" value="/SomeStaticForTestExample.html" />
                <add key="test.a.b.c.example.com" value="/SomePageForTestABC.html" />
            </rewriteMap>
        </rewriteMaps>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```